# Whats the correct cache key for webpack build on CI (cache invalidation)?

Tags: node.js, git, webpack, caching, continuous-integration

Caching on the CI is important. It speeds up the build and reduces costs.

It's very popular for speeding up `npm install`. People are caching the `node_modules` directory or the npm/yarn cache across builds. (the internet will tell you how that works)

Finding the correct cache key for working with `node_modules` is fairly easy: it's the hash of the lock file. If something in the lock file changes, it generates a new hash and the cache is "invalidated".

I'm trying to persist the webpack build cache. This is possible with [persistent caching](https://github.com/webpack/changelog-v5/blob/master/guides/persistent-caching.md) in webpack 5. Setting up the cache is easy, find the "correct" strategy to generate the cache key I find hard.

Lock file hash is certainly doesn't work. Stuff will change without lock file being touched.

I was thinking about creating a new cache entry every time something is merged to master/main using the commit hash as key. Then, when a feature branch is created, it can use this commit hash as cache key.

What is the best way to cache webpack builds on CI?